# Android Studio ListView items gravity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

I want to have my items in listview looking like a conversation in messenger.

There is simple code of recieving messages:

```
if (arrayList2.get(y).toString().equals(myEmail)) {
    arrayList.add(arrayList2.get(k).toString());

} else if (arrayList2.get(y).toString().equals(recipientEmail)) {
    arrayList.add(arrayList2.get(k).toString());
}

arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

When `array.get.....equals(myEmail)`, the messages are from me so, they should stay like they are. When `...equals(recipientEmail)`, I want text to be on the right of the screen/or listview and have an background of image, like classically in messenger

[image: Should be bacground of text]

[image: Or te best would be looking like this]

Answer (score 0):

You may create a row with 2 views. One on left and other on right. Based on your if condition you can make one of the views gone and the other visible. At any time only one view in that will be visible.

Another way of doing is to use single view in it and setting (left/right) gravity based on your condition.

You may refer `http://www.uandblog.com/How-to-Create-Chat-Application-using-Firebase-in-Android-`. See MainActivity.java and item.xml

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to add all Your messages in one `Arraylist` and create two layouts one of `sender` with left gravity and one of `receiver` with right gravity then make a logic like-

```
if(arraylist.get(position).getUserID==currentUser){
  senderLayout.setvisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  senderTextview.setText(arraylist.get(position).getText) 
} 
 else{
  senderLayout.setvisibility(View.GONE);
  receiverLayout.setvisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  recieverTextview.setText(arraylist.get(position).getText)
}
```

Do this in `getView` method of your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Use two TextView in raw file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.github.library.bubbleview.BubbleTextVew
    android:id="@+id/tv_chatRecive"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:angle="5dp"
    app:arrowHeight="12dp"
    app:arrowLocation="left"
    app:arrowPosition="5dp"
    app:arrowWidth="12dp"
    app:bubbleColor="@color/colorPrimary" />



<com.github.library.bubbleview.BubbleTextVew
    android:id="@+id/tv_chatSend"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/text_labelColoe"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:angle="5dp"
    app:arrowHeight="12dp"
    app:arrowLocation="right"
    app:arrowPosition="5dp"
    app:arrowWidth="12dp"
    app:bubbleColor="@android:color/white" />


   </RelativeLayout>
```

and in Adapter class use this kind of logic to manage  textview

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, final int position) {
    if (listChat.get(position).CHAT_SEND_RECIVE.equalsIgnoreCase("right")) {
        customViewHolder.tvSend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        customViewHolder.tvRecive.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        customViewHolder.tvSend.setText(listChat.get(position).CHAT_MESSAGE);
    } else if (listChat.get(position).CHAT_SEND_RECIVE.equalsIgnoreCase("left")) {
        customViewHolder.tvRecive.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        customViewHolder.tvSend.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        customViewHolder.tvRecive.setText(listChat.get(position).CHAT_MESSAGE);

    }

}
```

Add key in chat responce like just i add right and left

Answer (score 0):

**Here is complete example.**

Resources under drawable:

[image: out]
[image: in]

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.andrii.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/chat"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Message layout will looks like so (message.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/in_9">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:breakStrategy="balanced"
            android:maxWidth="200dp"
            android:text="test"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And finally in MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.andrii.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<Message> list=  new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(new Message(true, "hi"));
        list.add(new Message(false, "hello"));
        list.add(new Message(true, "how are you"));
        list.add(new Message(false, "I'm fine"));
        list.add(new Message(false, "Test test test test test"));
        RecyclerView view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.chat);
        view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        view.setAdapter(new ChatAdapter(this, list));
    }

    private class Message {
        private boolean misMine;
        private String mMessage;
        public Message (boolean mine, String message) {
            misMine = mine;
            mMessage = message;
        }
        public boolean isMine() { return misMine; }
        public String getMessage() { return mMessage; }
    }


    private class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private View mContainer;
        private TextView mMessage;

        public MessageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mMessage = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);
            mContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            mMessage.setText(message);
        }

        public void setMine(boolean isMine) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mContainer.getLayoutParams();
            params.gravity = isMine ? Gravity.RIGHT : Gravity.LEFT;

            mContainer.setBackgroundResource(isMine ? R.drawable.out_9 : R.drawable.in_9 );
            mContainer.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    }

    private class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageViewHolder> {
        private List<Message> mMessages;

        public ChatAdapter(Context context, List<Message> list) {
            mMessages = list;
        }

        @Override
        public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message, parent, false);

            MessageViewHolder holder = new MessageViewHolder(view);

            return holder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Message  message =  mMessages.get(position);

            holder.setMessage(message.getMessage());
            holder.setMine(message.isMine());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mMessages.size();
        }
    }
}
```

The result of code above:

[image]